# Is it possible to use if -> where in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a list of templates which user creates with some data (type of data is not important). The templates are stored in a table which have field `private` of `enum` type with values 0, 1 which means false/true. 
The main idea is that the each user can create a private template which can be see only by him, all other templates can see all system users. So my sql should be like this:

```
SELECT
    `templates`.`id`,
    `templates`.`name`,
    `templates`.`description`,
    `templates`.`datetime`,
    `users`.`username`
FROM
    (`templates`)
JOIN `users` ON `templates`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
-- WHERE
    -- `users`.`id` <> 1 AND `templates`.`private` = 0
ORDER BY
    `templates`.`datetime` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

In `where` i say that i need all rows except private where is not my id, but it miss my own private templates...

Comment: Do public templates have a value for `templates.id`, or just the private ones?

Comment: You should not use enum for true / false. Use tinyint instead.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no reason to JOIN the users table. You can get all public and your own private templates with

```
SELECT
    `templates`.`id`,
    `templates`.`name`,
    `templates`.`description`,
    `templates`.`datetime`,
FROM
    `templates`
WHERE
    `templates`.`user_id` = 42 OR `templates`.`private` = 0
```

I am assuming that the id of the current user is 42, substitute this with the real value when constructing the query.